# Retrieve row number from html table which match the given multiple cell values

Tags: javascript, html

I want to write one javascript function which can return row number of HTML table which matches the parameter values. Parameters would be column numbers and corresponding cell value.
Following is a sample HTML table.

```
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td>Id</td>
     <td>Name</td>
     <td>City</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><span>1</span></td>
     <td>ABC</td>
     <td style="display:none;"><input type="text" value="Pune"/></td>
     <td><input type="text" value="Pune"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><span>2</span></td>
     <td>XYZ</td>
     <td style="display:none;"><input type="text" value="Pune"/></td>
     <td><input type="text" value="Pune"/></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
```

Using this table, I want to call javascript function FindRowNumber(column no1, corresponding cell value1, column no2, corresponding cell value2);
Example :- FindRowNumber(1,"2",3,"Pune"); which should return row number 2.

Comment: *"I want to write one function"*. Great, where is it? Sounds more like you want somone else to do all of this for you and that's not how this site works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below code:

```js
function findRowNumber(cn1, v1, cn2, v2){
  var table = document.querySelector('#table');
  var rows = table.querySelectorAll("tr");
  var msg = "No such row exist"
  for(i=1;i<rows.length;i++){
    var tableData = rows[i].querySelectorAll("td");
    if(tableData[cn1-1].textContent==v1 && tableData[cn2].children[0].value==v2){
      msg = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  return msg;
}

console.log(findRowNumber(1,"2",3,"Pune"));
```

```css
table{
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 13px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,td{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>City</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>ABC</td>
        <td style="display:none;"></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="Delhi"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>XYZ</td>
        <td style="display:none;"></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="Pune"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>PQR</td>
        <td style="display:none;"></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="Mumbai"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Working. Thanks. But there is some change is the table structure.

Comment: I have voted up the answer. But there is one more little change in DOM. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No dear. Can you please remove input tag from hidden td.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using Jquery. Probably you take e1 and e3 as `td` index and e2 and e4 as `td` text then this code works as like your query.

```
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script>
       function FindRowNumber(e1,e2,e3,e4)
        {
          var aReturn  = false;
          $('table tr').each(function( index  ){

            var a  = $(this).children('td').eq(e1 - 1).text();
            var b  = $(this).children('td').eq(e3 - 1).text();
            if(a == e2 && b == e4)
             {
                aReturn = index;
             }

          });
         return(aReturn);  
        }

        var  a= FindRowNumber(1,"2",3,"Pune");
        console.log(a);
</script>
```

Comment: Working. Thanks. But there is some change is the table structure.

Answer (score 0):

> `document/Element.querySelectorAll` could be used to access elements as collection and `index` could be used to access respective element.

In provided example, `0` based indexes are considered as I feel manipulating indexes starting from `1` is needless.

```js
function FindRowNumber(colNum1, colNum1Value, colNum2, colNum2Value) {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('tr');
  for (var i = 0, iLen = elems.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    var tdElems = elems[i].querySelectorAll('td');
    if (tdElems[colNum1].textContent === colNum1Value && tdElems[colNum2].textContent === colNum2Value) {
      return i;
    }
  }
}

console.log(FindRowNumber(0, "1", 2, "Pune"));
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Id</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>City</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>ABC</td>
    <td>Pune</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>XYZ</td>
    <td>Pune</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Working. Thanks. But there is some change is the table structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery you can do that using a selector like this `tr:has(td:eq([cell1Index]):contains([cell1Value])):has(td:eq([cell2Index]):contains([cell2Value]))` Here is an example:

```
var rowIndex = $("tr:has(td:eq(0):contains('1')):has(td:eq(2):contains('Pune'))").index()
```

In this example, the indexes start from `0`.

In vanilla JavaScript, you can do the same thing using something like this:

```js
function getRowIndex(cell1Index, cell1Value, cell2Index, cell2Value){
  var index = -1;
  var rows = document.querySelectorAll("tr");
  for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
    var cell1 = rows[i].querySelector("td:nth-child("+cell1Index+")");
    var cell2 = rows[i].querySelector("td:nth-child("+cell2Index+")");
    if(cell1 && cell1.textContent == cell1Value && cell2 && cell2.textContent == cell2Value){
        index = i;
        break;
    }
  }
  return index;
}

console.log(getRowIndex(1, "1", 3, "Pune"));
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
   <td>Id</td>
   <td>Name</td>
   <td>City</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>ABC</td>
   <td>Pune</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>XYZ</td>
   <td>Pune</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Here, the cell indexes start from `1` but the row indexes start from `0`. You can add `1` to the return value of the function to have all indexes start from `1`;

Answer (score 0):

**Your initial question was: how to parse an HTML table with javascript.**

For this, you can first have a look at this answer: [JavaScript HTML table parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957955/javascript-html-table-parsing)

**After edit, you want to extract comparable values** from differently coded elements inside `<td>...</td>`

I suggest you code specific functions for each column and store them in an array at respective index.

Then your code can look like:

```
let getValue = [
    (e) => ..., // write your function for Id here
    (e) => e.textContent, // getter for Name value
    (e) => ...  // write your function for City here
];
function FindRowNumber (c1, v1, c2, v2) {
    let table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
    let rows = table.querySelectorAll("tr");
    return rows.reduce((acc, row, idx) => {
        if ( acc !== null  ) return acc; // match already found
        let cols = row.querySelectorAll("td");
        if ( !(getValue[c1](cols[c1]) === v1 && getValue[c2](cols[c2]) === v2) ) // non-matching row
            return acc;
        return idx; // match found!
    }, null);
}
```

Comment: Working. Thanks. But there is some change is the table structure.

Comment: Updated answer. I let you do the final work to get values from columns. Because this is another question and you may get downvoted for asking 2 questions. So please now choose your favorite answer :)